# Why simple domains like a.com, b.com or 0.com aren't registered?

Tags: domains

I tried to access the entire alphabet succeeded by .com and I found out that only q.com and z.com are real websites. I did the same thing with the numbers from 0 to 9 and I found no website. Why? What would I have to do to own the a.com domain?

Comment: Wikipedia has a page about it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-letter_second-level_domain

Answer (score 3):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-letter_second-level_domain):

> In 1993, the Internet Assigned Numbers Authority (IANA) explicitly reserved all single-letter and single-digit second-level domain names in the top-level domains com, net, and org, and grandfathered those that had already been assigned. In December 2005, ICANN considered auctioning these domains.

In a nutshell you can't own one as they are reserved and not available.